# Need help turning off the backlighting of My Sony Vaio laptop

Tags: backlight, vaio, sony

I have tried almost everything - this AU question is the last option.

I have set-up Ubuntu through a subsystem on Windows 10 to perform this. I just need the right guidance for success. I tried an old thread on which I had no success, [it was this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/477893/sony-vaio-keyboard-light-never-turns-off/477906#477906).

How can I turn off the backlighting of my Sony VAIO Laptop?

Comment: Do you have the directory `/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/` ?

Comment: mdirk  /sys/devices/platfor/sony-laptop/_kbd? I am  completely new to this ,so I am researching and getting answers I really want to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the following should do it, I found this solution to enable it for me (with a 1 instead of the 0). A reboot will be required too.

```
$ echo "options sony-laptop kbd_backlight=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/sony-laptop.conf
```